hldest of eplain with luatex not working
Consider following code:
\input eplain
\font\partfont=cmr10 at 40pt
\protected\def\pdfoutline {pdfextension outline}
\pdfoutline goto name {part1} count -1 {Mysec-pdf}%
\topglue 0pt plus 1fill
\hldest{}{}{part1}%
\partfont\centerline{Titel}

Luatex complains about hldest macro. How can I make it work? I am novice in plain tex.

you really shouldn't be using cmr10 with luatex, what is your intention here? luatex is a unicode system and cmr10 is a 127 character font without even European accented letters, it will work but negates many of teh features of luatex.

I use only English so it will work. I am writing a math book but latex and context are very slow. I can even work with pdftex. Luatex is nice because it has metapost buil-in. But I can have external asymptote images.

latex and context may be slow, but do you really gain much time by using plain if you have to ask all this basic questions to reimplement their features? I see the next questions about bookmarks and outlines coming ...

@UlrikeFischer Got to start somewhere. I have managed to get bookmarks and outlines done. I have decided to not use LuaTeX but stick to PDFTeX. As far as time is concerned a document which is processed by LaTeX in 30 second is done by PDFTeX in less than 2 seconds.

@Shiv your timings don't really correspond to anything expected and using plain tex for a book rather than as an example format for small examples in the texbook really makes no sense.  Especially if (as you comment elsewhere) you use miniltx which means inputting a large part of latex every time at run time rather than using a format where it has been parsed and tokenised in advance in the format. If you distribute the pdf it will be much harder to meet accessibility requirements (especially if you use cmr10) if you use plain tex.

@DavidCarlisle You are right. I will get rid of miniltx. I need url and graphicx packages only. Can you please tell me more about accessibility requirements? I do not understand why cmr10 font will get in the way for an English only book.

even in english you use punctuation which are not in unicode positions (eg left and right quote marks) there are some unicode mappings in place but using a Uniocde font makes things a lot easier.  Not sure what you mean by needing graphicx that uses miniltx of course, or do you mean you will replace by pdftex graphic primitives?

So what is your advice then. I have already written one book in ConTeXt. I was preparing for second. Should I continue using ConTeXt?

yes, personally I'd use latex as I've been maintaining it for 30+ years, but context is fine:-)

@Shiv Did you try OpTeX? It is fast like plain LuaTeX and implements almost all LaTeX features.

I managed to do with following code which does not use hldest:
\input eplain
\ifnum\luatexversion>84
  \def\pdfcatalog{\pdfextension catalog}
  \def\pdfdest{\pdfextension dest}
  \def\pdfoutline{\pdfextension outline}
\fi

\pdfcatalog{/PageMode /UseOutlines}

\font\partfont=cmr10 at 40pt
\pdfoutline goto name {part1} count -1 {Mysec-pdf}%
\topglue 0pt plus 1fill
\pdfdest name{part1} xyz%
\partfont\centerline{Titel}


LuaTeX changed the primitives a long time ago - as you using plain, you really should update your sources to use the new names

I have no clue. I just started reading TeXBook and eplain manual. Seems I will have to read LuaTeX manual as well.

Yes, that's the expectation if you are using plain - if you want to use any features using post-TeX90 primitives, you have to know about them yourself

Noted and thanks a lot for pointing it out.

You can read TeX in a Nutshell too https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf . The extended primitives (i.e. LuaTeX primitives too) are also mentioned here. Reading TeXbook only is not so practical today if we have several TeX extensions and we have different requirements for document features than in 1980.

It's still unclear to me what do you aim to do, but if you want to stick to eplain LuaTeX without further additions, you may save some time loading luatex85.sty instead of trying to rewrite the translations from LuaTeX to pdfTeX by hand, not forgetting to activate eplain's hyperlinks:
\input luatex85.sty
\input eplain
\enablehyperlinks

\pdfcatalog{/PageMode /UseOutlines}

\font\partfont=cmr10 at 40pt
\pdfoutline goto name {part1} count -1 {Mysec-pdf}%
\topglue 0pt plus 1fill
\pdfdest name{part1} xyz%
\partfont\centerline{Titel}
\bye

It's important to say \bye!
